# perl, comparing hashes, sub set

Tags: perl, hash, subset

I was wondering if there is any easy algorithms to compare to see if one hash is a subset of another hash.

For example, if

```
$HASH{A} = B;
$HASH{B} = C;
$HASH{C} = D;

$HASH2{A} = B;
$HASH2{B} = C;
```

then %HASH2 is a subset of %HASH.

Comment: Did you mean `$HASH2{A}` instead of `$HASH1{A}`?

Comment: @MattFenwick: Probably—I've gone ahead and fixed it. Gordon, if I'm mistaken, please feel free to revert my edit.

Answer (score 4):

This uses ["smart matching"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) (`~~`) and [`List::Util::first`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil#first_BLOCK_LIST)

```
use 5.010;
use List::Util qw<first>;

sub hash_is_subset { 
    my ( $hash, $cand ) = @_;
    return not defined( first { not $hash->{ $_ } ~~ $cand->{ $_ } } keys %$cand );
}

hash_is_subset( \%HASH, \%HASH2 );
```

Comment: Never heard of smart-match before.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Smart match can lead to surprises. E.g., is `{a => "hello"}` a subset of `{a => qr/./}`? Smart match says yes, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your hashes are simple (e.g., they don't contain references as values) you can do this with a simple loop:

```
sub is_subset {
    my ($h1, $h2) = @_;

    while (my ($k, $v) = each %$h1) {
        exists $h2->{$k} && $v eq $h2->{$k}
            or return;   # in case of list context, thanks davorg
    }
    return 1;
}
```

In English, that goes through each key, value pair in the first hash, and asks (a) is the key in the second hash and (b) if so, are the values the same? If it finds one that isn't, then the first hash isn't a subset of the second hash. Otherwise, it is.

If your hashes are more complicated, e.g., the value may be a hashref, then you first need to define 'subset' better (e.g., is `{ a => 1 }` a subset of `{ h2 => { a => 1 } }`), and probably use some recursion (or check CPAN).

Comment: @MattFenwick: Well, if you know the values are numbers, I'd change `eq` to `==`.

Comment: @MattFenwick Smart match operator works for either strings or integers `$a ~~ $b`

Comment: Probably best to use a bare `return` in place of `return 0`. Just in case the function gets called in list context.